# Gsuite Apps Script API : AdminLicenseManager.LicenseAssignments - error on .update

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

When doing this :

```
var results = AdminLicenseManager.LicenseAssignments
.update({userId: userId}, productId, skuId, userId);
```

I get this error.

```
GoogleJsonResponseException: skuId is required field
```

I have an issue understanding the "resource parameter" (first one) i guess.. but I am not sure.

vars are:

```
skuId = Google-Apps-Lite
userId = user@domain.com
productId = Google-Apps
resource = {userId=user@domain.com}
```

thanks for your help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the API Reference, [`LicenseAssignments.update`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/v1/reference/licenseAssignments/update) is used to "Reassign a user's product SKU with a different SKU in the same product."

Also on the reference page is the description of the required properties in the resource body: `productId`, `skuId`, and `userId`. These 3 values are the values that will be assigned to the `LicenseAssignment` identified by the "path" parameters. Note that only the `skuId` is writable.

```
const resource = {
  productId: ...,
  skuId: ...,
  userId: ...,
};
var oldProductId = ...;
var oldSkuId = ...;
var oldUserId = ...;
var updatedLicenseAssignment = AdminLicenseManager.LicenseAssignments
  .update(resource, oldProductId, oldSkuId, oldUserId);
```

Consider using [`.patch`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/licensing/v1/reference/licenseAssignments/patch) instead of `.update` if you prefer to only supply the new `skuId`.